# Target image captions using a macro in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, caption

I'm currently working on a little macro for Word using VBA to scan a report and just highlight all the crossreferences. Now hihglighting the TypeFields that are references was quite easy.
I can't seem to figure out, how to target the captions of the referenced images. I don't want them to be connected to each other (not yet) but even just finding them seems impossible.
I now want to know, if it is even possible to target those little captions or if I am just missing something in the VBA documentation.

I've tried to use the InlineShapes.Caption, which resulted in nothing (InlineShapes works fine though, I can resize and delete images no problem). I've also tried to just select the Captions, but with using Selection I just end up with the images again. I have also tried to extract the caption via InlineShape.Text, no results. As well as InlineShape.Caption.Text, and InlineShape.CaptionLabel.Text, which are all not recognised objects (if I remember correctly, I tried so much)

This is the little code that I came up with, which finds references, and highlights them, as well as delete images.

```
Sub ReferenceHighlight()
    'Define the range as the whole document
    Dim docRange As Range
    Set docRange = ActiveDocument.Range
    'Define all Fields in the Document
    Dim fld As Word.Field
    'Define an incremental integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    'Define all Pictures in the Document
    Dim image As InlineShape
    For Each image In docRange.InlineShapes
        image.Delete
    Next image
    For Each fld In docRange.Fields
        If fld.Type = wdFieldRef Then
             fld.Result.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        End If
    Next fld
End Sub
```

Comment: Captions inserted using the Insert Caption function use the Caption style. You can use `Find` to find styles. Instead of just making up code to see if it works I suggest that you learn to use IntelliSense and the Object Browser.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it now using the `Find` in combination with the algorithm from taller. i really just wanted to know, if there is any kind of data structure a caption is stored as, like wdRefField for the references. 
As for IntelliSense, yeah, I should probably listen more to what my program tells me to I can and can't do.

Comment: No, as you probably realised by now, a caption is really just a piece of text that happens to be in a nearby paragraph. They aren't even necessarily in paragraphs with Caption style. So you can only easily find them programmatically if the document's editors have used a consistent approach, e.g. where they always come after the related object and have the same style, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try.

```vb
    For Each fld In docRange.Fields
        If fld.Type = wdFieldRef Then
            fld.Select
            Selection.Expand xlLine
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        End If
    Next fld
```

---

- A more efficient way to highlight captions. (***@Timothy Rylatt*** posts the comment before my answer)

```vb
Sub HightLightCaption()
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Caption")
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```